# Get SVN HEAD Revision and make Folder

Tags: svn, batch-file, command, mkdir

I want to get the SVN Revison and make an Folder with the current Date and Revision number.
I can't figure out how to make this Folder.

My Idea was this:

```
cd c:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin
set var = svn info svn://SVNTRUNC|find "Revision"
mkdir C:\%DATE% - %var%
pause
```

But setting the variable dont work.

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a variable from process output:

Method 1

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('svn info svn://SVNTRUNC ^|find "Revision" ') do set var=%%i
```

Method 2

```
svn info svn://SVNTRUNC|find "Revision" >tempfile
set /p var=<tempfile
```

either of which should set `var` to the ENTIRE contents of the line containing `Revision` in `svn`'s output.

If you'd show us what the general format of that line is, maybe we'd be able to refine this.

**BUT** batch ***DOES*** recognise and include spaces in a simple `set` statement, so had your first try worked, the environment variable `"var "` would have been set.